# Type deducing saves references and cv

Tags: c++, templates

I've read templete function remove references and cv from deduced types, however in this example I deduce type T as `const int&`
Could you please help me with references where this case is described (cppreference or Mayers)

I am using MSVS 2017.

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {};

template <class T>
void boo(const MyClass<T>& mycl)
{
    MyClass<T> mycl2; //mycl2 is MyClass<const int&> instead of MyClass<int>
    T{}; //T is deduced as const int& !!!
}

void main()
{
    MyClass<const int&> mycl{};
    const MyClass<const int&>& mycl_ref = mycl;
    boo(mycl_ref);
}
```

Comment: Deduced template types show up in functions and the issue of reference and const loss is present. There is no type being deduced (e.g., from an argument) here. const int and int are different types.

Comment: is T type deduced from mycl_ref or not?

Comment: T is deduced from the type of the object, which is `MyClass<const int&>`. So T is always `const int&`. If it’s necessary to remove the const ref classification, there are a number of tools in the type_traits library. Also, creating a const ref to pass to a function is probably wrong too. Simply calling `boo(my_cl)` will call it with the const ref. It means that the function won’t modify the structure and can sometimes speed up processing when using larger classes.

Comment: _"I've read templete function remove references and cv from deduced types"_ -- read where? To me, that looks like either a misreading or a bad resource.